# Retrieve polymorphic model instances

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, relational-database

Using **Laravel 5.1**, I'm trying to create a dynamic table where I can associate multiple item types with a `module`. I went with a [Polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) table and set the `morphable_ids` and `morphable_types` per module as such:

```
id  module_id morphable_id morphable_type
1       1          1       App/Enemy
2       2          2       App/Enemy
3       3          1       App/Item
```

I get my modules through associated `tasks`, aka `modules` are eager loaded in with tasks. When I drill down into my task from the API call, and check `module_items`, it shows the literal `morphable_id`/`morphable_type` rather than the `App\Enemy` or `App\Item` instances I was looking for:

```
more task obj properties...
"module":{
   "id" : 1
   "module_items":[
      {
        "id": 3,
        "module_id": "3",
        "morphable_id": "1",
        "morphable_type": "App/Item"
      }
   ]
 }
```

So my question is, how can I actually retrieve the polymorphic model instance (like, I retrieve `App\Item` of id `1` for module `1`)?

Here is some more information:

**Models:**

Task: loads with modules

```
class Task extends Model
{

    protected $with = ['module'];


    public function module()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Module::class);
    }
}
```

Module

```
class Module extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['module_items'];

    public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }

    public function module_items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ModuleItem::class);
    }
}
```

Polymorphic `ModuleItem` model

```
class ModuleItem extends Model
{
    public function typeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function module()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Module::class);
    }
}
```

Polymorphic relation on Item

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function module_item_types()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\ModuleItem', 'typeable');
    }
}
```

Polymorphic relation on Enemy

```
class Enemy extends Model
{
    public function module_item_types()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\ModuleItem', 'typeable');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent@morphMany`:

```
/**
 * Define a polymorphic one-to-many relationship.
 *
 * @param  string  $related
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string  $type
 * @param  string  $id
 * @param  string  $localKey
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
 */
public function morphMany($related, $name, $type = null, $id = null, $localKey = null)
{
    $instance = new $related;

    // Here we will gather up the morph type and ID for the relationship so that we
    // can properly query the intermediate table of a relation. Finally, we will
    // get the table and create the relationship instances for the developers.
    list($type, $id) = $this->getMorphs($name, $type, $id);

    $table = $instance->getTable();

    $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

    return new MorphMany($instance->newQuery(), $this, $table.'.'.$type, $table.'.'.$id, $localKey);
}
```

If you follow the rabbit hole down through `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent@getMorphs` you'll see that the DB table names are inferred through the `$name` param if `$type` is null. Your column names are being inferred as `typeable_id` and `typeable_type` instead of `morphable_id` and `morphable_type`.

Once that's fixed, you should be able to access the `ModuleItem`'s type like `$module_item->typeable` (or whatever you rename the relationship to). If you wanted to eager load the type instance you would update `ModuleItem`:

```
class ModuleItem extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['typeable'];

    public function typeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function module()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Module::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, however when I change it to `return $this->morphMany(ModuleItem::class, 'typeable', 'morphable');` to explicitly name the `type`, it doesn't grab the instance